# pointwise convergence, how can I show that $f_n \not\to 0$ uniformly?

Tags: analysis

I am given the following exercise:

Let $\displaystyle{f_n:(0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}}$.

Show that $f_n \to 0 \text{ pointwise }, x \in (0,+\infty) \text{ and } that f_n \not\to 0\text{ uniformly } at (0,+\infty)$.

To show that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, I have tried the following:

Let $x>0, \text{ constant :}$

$$|f_n(x)|=|\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}| \leq \frac{1}{nx} \to 0, \text{ when } n \to +\infty$$

So we get that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise.

Is that what I have done so far right? Also,how can I show that $f_n \not\to 0$ uniformly?

Answer (score 2):

In order for $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, you will need for any $\epsilon > 0$ an index $N$ with $n \in N \implies |f_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$. In particular, there must exist $N$ with the property that $|f_N(x)| < \dfrac 12$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

What is $\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x)$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x)=1$$
right? So,could I take any $\epsilon<1$?

Comment: Yes, the condition $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ is violated on $(0,\infty)$ for all $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2n}$.
Then $$f_n(x_n)=\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

So for $\epsilon < \frac{2}{\pi}$ one cannot chose an $N$ independent of $x$.
Basically if you look at the graphs of the successive $f_n$ there will be a bump of constant hight $\frac{2}{\pi}$ but which "travels" toward $0$. It will eventually pass by any $x$ but all $x$'s do not come within $\epsilon$ of $0$ at the same time.